# How to make rxjs v7 streams hot everywhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, stream, observable

I'm using RxJS v7.

I noticed when I create new observable from scratch or using `map`, `scan`, `merge` or other operators, the observable called multiple times unless using `share` if I use a variable holding it multiple times. Like below

```
let share_a = false
let share_b = false
if (process.argv[2] === 'share_a') {
  share_a = true
}
if (process.argv[3] === 'share_b') {
  share_b = true
}
console.log({ share_a, share_b })
const { map, merge, tap, share, Observable } = require('rxjs')
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
let a = new Observable(async subscriber => {
  await sleep(100)
  console.log('a called')
  subscriber.next('a')
})
if (share_a) {
  a = a.pipe(share())
}
let b = a.pipe(map(() => 'b'), tap(x => console.log(`${x} called`)))
if (share_b) {
  b = b.pipe(share())
}
const c = merge(a, b).pipe(map(() => 'c'), tap(x => console.log(`${x} called`)))
merge(a,b,c).subscribe(console.log)
```

```
% node src/rxjsTest.js
{ share_a: false, share_b: false }
a called
a
a called
b called
b
a called
c called
c
a called
b called
c called
c
% node src/rxjsTest.js share_a
{ share_a: true, share_b: false }
a called
a
b called
b
c called
c
b called
c called
c
% node src/rxjsTest.js share_a share_b
{ share_a: true, share_b: true }
a called
a
b called
b
c called
c
c called
c
%
```

How can I make every observable shared without calling `share` every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no settings which would do this for you and it's pretty atypical to want this and it comes with serious performance implications.

That being said, you an just create a new function/method to handle this for you.

For example:

```ts
Observable.prototype.pipeHot = function (...operators) {
  return this.pipe(
    ...operators,
    share()
  );
}

// Make **a** without mixing observables and promises
let a = timer(100).pipeHot(
  map(_ => 'a'), 
  tap(v => console.log(`${v} called`))
);

let b = a.pipeHot(
  map(_ => 'b'), 
  tap(v => console.log(`${v} called`))
);

const c = merge(a, b).pipeHot(
  map(_ => 'c'), 
  tap(v => console.log(`${v} called`))
);

merge(a,b,c).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is it atypical? Why does it make performance issues despite reduction of execution count?

Comment: Most of the time, you don't need hot observables. You can make some performance gains when you're memorizing the result of a long computation, but otherwise you're storing values in memory and creating all the infrastructure that allows multiple observers to the same observable when it's not necessary.

Comment: Does hot observable store values? I think values are discarded if the observable is not subscribed. Execute my script without `await sleep(100)` and with `share_a` argument. You can verify that.

Comment: You're right, a hot observable may not come with any replay. Even so, it must maintain a list of observers in order to remit the same value to multiple observers. This is effectively done by create a new Subject. This comes with further memory footprint and indirection - all of it nice when needed and a waste of resources when not.

In general, subscribing to an observable is like calling a function. There's some work you want done. Promises do their work when you create them, not when you `await` them, so how and when they're used differ appropriately.